# Updating list in view Asp.net mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have 2 lists in a view. What I want to do is that pick elements from list1 and update list2 with selected elements everytime I pick one. I tried to use `PartialView` (I don't know if it's correct approach or not) but I failed. I have a function in controller that fills a list by selected items. What needs to be done is updating the view dynamically. Can you suggest me a roadmap for this?

**Update**

I forgot to say that I have done this with javascript. But I feel like it's the long way when it comes to some validations (checking duplications etc.)

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#allPlayersList a").on("click", function () {
        var options = $(this).clone();
        $("#thisWeekList").append(options);
    });
});
```

Comment: If this answer helped, then pls accept it as the answer by clicking the grey tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create an html list. See if this link helps. https://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/QNQrvz. You can also populate the values from database
 Then you can get the selected element by javascript like this

```
var input = document.getElementById('Something').value;
```

**Update after edited question**

You can try something like

```
var listSelection = document.getElementById('Something').value;
```

Now you can create an api in the backend which accepts this value and returns a list based on it. Call that Api like this

```
&.ajax({
      url: //url of api
      data: {exactNameOfApiParameter : listSelection  },
      success: function(data){

        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
             $('<li>', { text: data[i] }).appendTo($('#list2'));
        }
      }
})
```

Make sure that id of second list is list2.